# Right way to convert string into NSDate?(iphone)

Tags: iphone, string, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my app I store the date as a string("MM/dd/YYYY" format). In the DB. later when I retrieve the string I have to compare two dates, how do I achieve this?

If I had used the"YYYY/MM/dd" format I could have directly compared it as strings.
Now I have to convert back into NSDate object using "nsdateformatter" and "dateFromString". But I get a constant date value using this no matter what I do.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:@"12/23/2046"];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

Result:

```
2046-12-23 00:00:00 +0800
```

Comment: hmmm interesting! with"yyyyy" Its working and when I used "YYYY" it was not. Now y would that be?

Comment: Thanks! If not taken care, even the smallest of the things can  surprise u.