# How to convert this string into nsdate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to nsdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate)

I have this string `Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100`

How can I convert it into NSDate

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss +HHmm"];
NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100"];
NSLog(@"-->%@",myDate);
```

The nslog gives

```
-->2012-12-06 19:30:33 +0000
```

This code is not working properly kindly help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: It is already converted into correct format, what you want now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095500/convert-string-into-nsdate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162058/right-way-to-convert-string-into-nsdateiphone

Comment: Use the search feature before posting!

Comment: I searched but my problem is i hve time 08:40 but while nslog it is 07:40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your comments on all the answers, and I woul like to say, you are getting confused with the time zone.

07:40 is the time of GMT, and while you are having 08:40 +1000 (one hour 00 min) so these are same. Similarly while regenerating and printing it will print in GMT.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];
NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100"];
NSLog(@"--> %@",myDate);


NSString *rechange=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];

NSLog(@"==> %@",rechange);
```

Comment: The `hh` hour format is incorrect, since there is not AM/PM switch in the date you should have used the 24 hour `HH` format string.

Comment: And you code will fail on iOS devices where the default language is not set to english, like may answer stated you need to supply the local.

Comment: so how to do that?  `[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];` has to added??

Comment: is der diffnce between iphone and mac? me wanted for mac only. and this work fine

Comment: Well if the system even OSX is set to Dutch for example, datformatter will try to parse the date as a Dutch date. The Dec will be fine but May will be Mei, which it will not be able to parse, there you should always set the the locale if the date contains localized elements.

Comment: This is what I learnt today...Thanks a lot rckoenes.

Answer (score 2):

You code is almost correct, but there are some mistakes.

First the year is not `YYYY` but just `yyyy` and `hh` is not the 24 hour is incorrect since the hours are present as 24 hours thus you shouhd use `HH`. Next is the timezone offset, wich is not `+HHmm` but just `Z`.
And now the most importen part, your date has the day and a month as a written language but the app might run on an non english language os the parsing will not work, you will have to add a locale.

The full code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100"];
NSLog(@"-->%@",myDate);
```

Comment: it prints 07:40, i need 08:40 in time

Comment: No the 07:40 is correct, the time is present as GMT, wich is offset to you time by 1 hour, thus if you use NSDateFormatter with the system timezone the correct time is show relative to the timezone offset.

Comment: Yes, now i understood. I was very silly of this.

Comment: I cant vote up, how can I, i dont hve 15 points.

Comment: I earned vote up, so for you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need you change your final `+HHmm` to `ZZZZ`.

It's the time zone, not the time again.

Comment: Do you have `ZZZZ` or `+ZZZZ`?

Comment: Ok..now it is --> 2012-12-07 07:40:33 +0000

Comment: Use a second date formatter if you want it output in a different format.

Comment: I want result is same formate as in input string

Comment: I give up then. What do you want to convert from and to? You now have working code which converts your starting string to an NSDate object.